# Translation of "side dish"

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to translate this sentence to Esperanto:

> You make rice and a side-dish.

How can "side dish" be translated?

> Vi pretigas rizon kaj **???**.

Comment: Wouldn't rice already be a [side dish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_dish) in most meals it occurs in?

Comment: You're right! It is not the best example sentence, but I'm more interesed in the translation of "side dish". :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> side-dish = krommanĝaĵo

As a *dish* also comes in the sense of additional separate food, hence the concretisation `aĵ` in Esperanto. Dutch *Bijgerecht*, German *Nebengericht/Nebenspeise*.

However *plado*, literally the dish, plate, is also defined in E-o to mean its content, the food. So with *plado* one covers all meanings.

Without the meaning of a *separate* dish:

> garnaĵo = tio kio garnas la ĉefan manĝaĵon. Like potatoes with as main meal fish.

Bulgarian *гарнитура* ("garnitura"), Dutch *garnering*, French *accompagnement*.

Comment: _garnaĵo_ is the right one for me. Though at home we always use _akompan-_

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest either *kromplado* or even just quite literally *flanka plado*, as *flanka* can have the meaning *neĉefa* (according to [Vortaro](http://vortaro.net/#flanka))

Comment: _Flanka_ gets associated in my mind to something, that will be left aside, not to be eaten.